# Containerizing vs. Sandboxing vs. Layering vs. Virtualizing vs. whatever

Tags: virtualization

What is the right term to describe what solutions like Invincea/Bromium are offering?

Is there a difference?

Comment: Security by isolation

Answer (score 1):

*Sandboxing*, because you are "penning in" an application so that it doesn't trail dirt everywhere.

*Virtualization* often allows easier sandboxing, since the virtualized environment already offers the required behaviour for a sandbox; but in many virtualized environment it is possible for a process to recognize it's virtualized and interface with the virtualization host, and from there try to manipulate the outside environment. If a virtualization environment takes care *not* to let this happen, we might call it *sandboxed virtualization* to stress this fact.

*Layering* is a different concept altogether: it means that something is designed to offer (and ask) services at different abstraction levels, usually with some sort of black-boxing so that a layer doesn't know the details of what another layer *does*. A prime example would be TCP/IP.

And finally "containerizing" refers to the practice of bundling together several objects (for example a web server, a database server etc.) for ease of deployment. Again, one way of containerizing such would be to create a virtual environment (virtual appliance).

So all those terms are related, but their meaning is different (maybe ot always by very much).